# Kill a child process created with clone()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I need to create many child processes using the clone() function. I have to use "Busy waiting"
to wait for the change of some shared variables.

How can I kill this child process once I know that I won't use it anymore?

thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ymmt2005/8120885

Answer (score 0):

> How can I kill this child process once I know that I won't use it
>   anymore?

- by using `kill` to send this child process a fatal signal, unless you used `CLONE_THREAD` - in that case see n.m.'s comment.